# filemaker send email with userdata

Tags: email, filemaker

How can I send an email in Filemaker Pro 18 with user data?

I tried something like below but it didn't evaluate and just send the whole thing as a text.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, instead of using "+", just use "&" and it'll concatenate the string and variable